# Minimum modulus principle - looks like a counterexample?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

The [minimum modulus principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle) states that if $f$ is holomorphic within a bounded domain D, continuous up to the boundary of D, and non-zero at all points, then $|f (z)|$ takes its minimum value on the boundary of $D$.

Now, I think I don't understand something. If we consider $f(z) = e^z$ with $D:=\{z\in C: |z|\le 1\}$, then $\min\limits_{z\in S}|f(z)| = 1$ where $z=0$, and $z\not\in \partial S$, i.e. not in the boundary of $S$. What am I missing here?

Comment: What is $f(-1)$?

Comment: Right, I got too stressed out today. Thank you :)

Comment: As a small addendum, it's probably worth making sure you understand why neither $e^{z^2}$ (which takes on the value $e\gt 1$ at $z=-1$) nor $e^{|z|^2}$ are counterexamples.

Comment: For $e^{z^2}$, the minimum is achieved at $z = i$. But for the other function, if $z=0$, aren't we getting the minimum not at the boundary?

Comment: I guess $e^{|z|^2}$ is not analytic at $z=0$. So if the domain is $1/2 < |z| < 1$, for example, then we're getting the minimum at the "lower" boundary.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum of $|f(z)|$ on $D$ is not $1$ but $1/e$, which is achieved at $z=-1$ on the boundary.